# ¿Cómo puedo instanciar una clase abstracta en php?

Tags: php, poo

Tengo una clase por archivo y requiero utilizar un atributo de una clase abstracta pero en un archivo externo

**¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?**

Ya que al hacer ésto en el archivo en donde lo necesito: `$this->valorNecesario();` no muestra nada y es como si tuviera un error, pero no me muestra ni si quiera eso.

Agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, añade algo de código para ver como sobrescribes la clase abstracta y como haces uso de ella. De otra forma, es complicado ayudarte.

Comment: Muéstranos dónde estas usando `$this->valorNecesario()`. Si es el otro archivo... cuál es el valor de `$this`?

Answer (score 1):

> Las clases definidas como abstractas no se pueden instanciar y cualquier clase que contiene al menos un método abstracto debe ser definida como tal.

[Fuente](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.abstract.php)

Asi pues tienes que heredar de tu clase abstracta e instancia la clase heredada, algo asi:

```
abstract class BaseCuadrado {
   public $altura = 1;  
}

class Cuadrado extends BaseCuadrado {

}

/* Esto daria un error : FATAL ERROR Cannot instantiate abstract class BaseCuadrado on line number... */
// $miCuadrado = new BaseCuadrado();

/*Pero si instanciamos la clase heredada todo va bien*/
$miCuadrado = new Cuadrado();

var_dump($miCuadrado->altura);
```

**Como no se introducir bloques de código te pongo una captura**

[image: Te pongo una captura]

Por otro lado puedes intentar mostrar los errores agregando a tu archivo estas lineas:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: No conocía la existencia de PHPTester